# \addcontentsline Also Adding to the Depth of a Minipage

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, minipage

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=blue,
    colback=blue!30,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\section*{\logo{April 1}}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\begin{center} 
{\LARGE{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{\textit{April, come she will}}}}}
\end{center}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\normalsize\color{black} 1. Add to contents.}

\begin{center}
\begin{normalsize}
\begin{minipage}{4.25in}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}
\end{normalsize}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

However, when I run the code with the following line not commented out

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\normalsize\color{black} 1. Add to contents.}
```

I get

[image]

QUESTION: Why is the spacing between the minipage and the text above it increased when I make use of the `\addcontentsline` command? And how may I prevent this from happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two adjacent display environments combine the space adding the maximum of the space after the first, and the space before the second.

By adding a write node between the two you prevent the second `center` "seeing" the space added by the first so you get the sum.

The `\addcontentsline{toc}` should not be added at that point in any case as the space adds a page break point so the table of contents entry may end up referencing the wrong page.

Add the write at the same line as the text.

Not directly related but in

```
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\section*{\logo{April 1}}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
```

neither `center` nor `LARGE` affect the formatting of `\section*` so this is just a complicated way to add vertical space.

Comment: Thank you. I have shifted the `addcontentsline`command to the end of the text in the minipage and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: @David Carlisle Now I do not understand the effect of `\addcontentsline`. It seems that is inserting something that manifest itself when centering the text.

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\centering
    
\textcolor{red!70!black}{\LARGE April, come she will}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{1. Add to contents.}
    
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\ 2. Add to contents.}
\textcolor{green!50!black}{\LARGE April, come she will}

\end{document}`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjYzE.jpg

Comment: it looks like you have a space between `will` and the `\write` node so that will make the text off centre.

Comment: Right! Solved writing `will}%`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but an illustration.  Normally TeX ignores multiple `\par`s, but if you put anything else between them...

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip=\baselineskip
\begin{document}
\verb|\par\par|
\par\par
\verb|\par\hbox{}\par|
\par\hbox{}\par
end
\end{document}
```